# transferUserInfo(_:) doesn't support sending classes

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to use the WatchConnectivity library to transfer data from my watch to my iPhone. Using the method transferUserInfo(_:), I found out that I can transfer any struct, being an Int, Double or String, but I can't transfer a class with data.

What is so interesting, is that the documentation describes the function as:

```
func transferUserInfo(_ userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) -> WCSessionUserInfoTransfer
```

I would, therefore, see Any as being anything a struct or a class. I don't read specifically that the method doesn't support transferring classes. Should I have read this from the sentence in the Parameter description: "A dictionary of property list **values** that you want to send"?

Does anybody has some better insight on this method than I can get from the information?

Comment: I think "**property list** values" is the important part. It could definitely be more explicit. Keep in mind that this is coming from Obj-C and not Swift. In a more modern API, for example, I'd expect it to accept a `Codable`, but this is not a pure-Swift situation.

Comment: @jnpdx, you are so right and I'm not a good reader :). The dictionary can only be property list values and that supports only a limited number of values. Thanks.

Comment: Hi jnpdx, if you put your comment in a well formulated answer, I can reward you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation specifies that the `userInfo` parameter is:

> A dictionary of property list values that you want to send

The "property list" bit of this is important. If you look at the [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/Articles/StructureAndContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001171-CJBEJBHH) we can see that the data types for property list values are:

> CFString, CFNumber, CFBoolean, CFDate, and CFData

(These get bridged to the appropriate Objective-C and Swift types when we use them in those contexts. Also, dictionaries and arrays of these types work.)

Trying to include your own `class` types as values (although it doesn't throw a compile-time error) in the `userInfo` should not be expected to transfer at runtime.